# ArcGIS ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, setExtent

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have a layer made with `ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer` like this:

```
return esriLoader.loadModules([
  'esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer',
  'esri/layers/ImageParameters',
  'esri/InfoTemplate'
]).then(([ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, ImageParameters, InfoTemplate]) => {

  const infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate();
  infoTemplate.setContent(this.handleContentChange);
  infoTemplate.setTitle(this.props.intl.formatMessage({ id: 'layers.popup.title' }));
  const imageParams = new ImageParameters();
  imageParams.layerIds = [layerCode];
  imageParams.layerOption = ImageParameters.LAYER_OPTION_SHOW;
  imageParams.transparent = true;

  const layer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(layerUrl, {
    id: layerId,
    opacity: 0.5,
    imageParameters: imageParams,
    infoTemplates: { [layerCode]: { infoTemplate: infoTemplate } }
  });

  esriMap.addLayer(layer)
```

I want to set the extent of the layer that I'm rendering to fit what it's rendered. The problem that I see is the `featureExtent` and `initialExtent` comes from the service, and it's the same for each service. But some layers are in different parts of the map, some are big, some are very small, so I need a way to zoom to what it's showed in the map. How can I set the extent on those service to fit it?

For example, with: `esriMap.setExtent(layer.initialExtent, true)` doesn't work, because in the services
[image]

I have this extents:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since ArcGIS Server 10.4, the [query](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/query-map-service-layer-.htm) operation on a layer supports the `returnExtentOnly` parameter. You could use this to together with `where=1=1` to get the extent of the layer, and then zoom to that extent.

The documentation for the Query object in JavaScript ([v3](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/query-amd.html), [v4](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-tasks-support-Query.html)) doesn't explicitly mention this option, so you'll have to add it to the QueryTask's URL manually.